# Where is the "server log" for Tomcat when running externally from IntelliJ Ultimate?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, intellij-idea, runtime

When running my [Vaadin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin) app on [Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) 8.5 externally from [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) Ultimate 2017.2 on macOS Sierra, I get an error message:

> Artifact timepiece-ui:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.

➠ Where is this ‘server log’?

When I look in `apache-tomcat-8.5.20` > `logs`, the folder is empty. Indeed, I cannot find any trace of my app being deployed within `apache-tomcat-8.5.20`.

➠ Is there some other place where IntelliJ+Tomcat is placing my app and the server logs?

[image: screen shot of "Run/Debug Configurations" > "Logs" dialog box]

[image: screen shot of "Application Servers" dialog with Apache Tomcat configuration displayed]

Comment: There are "Tomcat localhost log" and "Tomcat catalina Log" tabs inside "Debug" bottom frame

Comment: Similar: [*Where do messages sent to System.err go when using Tomcat externally to run a web app from IntelliJ?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59132401/642706).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA shows the log files [you configure](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/setting-log-options.html) in the Run/Debug configuration settings as the separate tabs in the Run or Debug tool window.

[image: screenshot of Run/Debug Configurations dialog, Logs tab]

For Tomcat the actual logs are placed under `CATALINA_BASE/logs` directory. The  value of the `CATALINA_BASE` set by IntelliJ IDEA will be printed in the console of the Run or Debug tool window.

You can also find the log files under [idea.system.path](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519)`/tomcat/<configuration name>/logs/`.

Comment: Ahhh, I see now. I assumed `CATALINA_BASE` would be within the Tomcat folder. But, no, it was: `/Users/basilbourque/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2017.2/tomcat/Unnamed_timepiece_3`. I've no idea why the `Unnamed_` was prefixed, but otherwise makes sense. That folder does have a nested `logs` folder populated with log files. Thanks! And as Jerry06 commented, IntelliJ does indeed display the logs as tabs in the server output panel, but I had not noticed. By the way, I do not see any hash involved in the folder name, but otherwise this Answer is spot-on correct.

Comment: Update: Now in IntelliJ 2022.2 Beta I find the logs in `/Users/my_user_name/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.2/tomcat/some_UUID_hex_string/logs`

Comment: For Tomcat the actual logs are placed under CATALINA_BASE/logs directory - this is exactly what i needed to know. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 22):

## IntelliJ displays Tomcat logs

The [accepted Answer by CrazyCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45666862/642706) is correct.

In addition, as commented by Jerry06, IntelliJ Ultimate does automatically display the logs as tabs in the server output pane.

The files backing those logs are stored in the `CATALINA_BASE` as explained in [the other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45666862/642706).

[image: screen shot of server output panel showing (a) tabs for logs, (b) 'CATALINA_BASE' path logged]

Comment: How could I not see that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, I'm not sure if its the same for IntelliJ Ultimate, but in the community edition, you can find the Catalina server logs in **/home/.SmartTomcat///${catalina.base}/logs**. If you couldn't find the **.SmartTomcat** folder, enable **Show hidden files** in your file explorer. Since community edition of IntelliJ doesn't support Tomcat, we need to use the Smart tomcat plugin and so the server logs are available in the SmartTomcat directory.