# Deployment of generated Maven Spring Projekt doesnt work

Tags: spring, tomcat, intellij-idea, deployment

I am using IntelliJ and I have created a new `SpringProjekt` with the maven `Archetype` `co:ntier` `spring-mv-archetyp`. Now I want to deploy the project on a Tomcat 9 Server but this is not working. I am getting the following Stacketrace:

```
Connected to server
[2018-05-18 10:22:43,232] Artifact games:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2018-05-18 10:22:43,232] Artifact games:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2018-05-18 10:22:43,238] Artifact games:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2018-05-18 10:22:43,238] Artifact games:war exploded: com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JmxAdminException: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: C:\Users\Tobi\IdeaProjects\games\target\games not found for the web module.
[2018-05-18 10:22:43,244] Artifact games:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2018-05-18 10:22:43,245] Artifact games:war: com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JmxAdminException: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: C:\Users\Tobi\IdeaProjects\games\target\games.war not found for the web module.
18-May-2018 22:22:52.920 INFORMATION [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [E:\entwicklung\apache-tomcat-9.0.8\webapps\manager]
18-May-2018 22:22:53.139 INFORMATION [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [E:\entwicklung\apache-tomcat-9.0.8\webapps\manager] has finished in [218] ms
```

Thank you for your help and I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Check the artifact you are deploying: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html.

Comment: i am using games:war:exploded

Comment: Check the [server log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45666862/104891) for details as suggested. What's the artifact output directory?

Comment: there is no error in one of the both log files.

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://hastebin.com/uxijuyisom.xml there is the code from my project

Comment: It's not the MCVE, since it's missing IntelliJ IDEA run configuration and artifacts. Zip and share the project directory.

Comment: here ist the complete project https://www.dropbox.com/s/y287a16h54sjvei/WinRAR-ZIP-Archiv%20%28neu%29.zip?dl=0

Comment: Artifact build step is [missing here](https://i.imgur.com/3kbbi4l.png), therefore the output directory is empty and there is nothing to deploy. Also your `pom.xml` in the shared project contains `*` at the very beginning which makes it invalid and import/build will fail.

Comment: thank you for your help. The missing Build was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Artifact build step is [missing here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wAU5.png), therefore the output directory is empty and there is nothing to deploy.