# unable to see artifact deployment error at intellij

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, artifact

I use Intellij 15 and tomcat to deploy my JEE application and I was not able to deploy an artifact. The problem is I can not see the log... It says

"Jun 01, 2018 9:55:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/tap] startup failed due to previous errors"

I checked the logs of tomcat but I found no clue about the error of the artifact deployment. Do you know the place where I can find the artifact deployment errors?

Comment: Did you checked *all* the logs of tomcat? Sometimes the errors are in the logs of tomcat (catalina.log) itself instead of the application logs.

Comment: I checked all the logs of tomcat. All of them in the path. There is still no error about the reason of artifact  deployment. It should be somewhere else

Comment: @user2307786 are you sure you've checked Tomcat logs under IDE system directory? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45666862/104891.

Comment: Yes I checked IDE system directory. Even there is no clue about that .

Answer (score 0):

When deploying via IntelliJ perhaps this might be of help for you:
in the menu: `Help -> show log in explorer/finder`. It opens the log folder in your file explorer and you can check `idea.log`. Perhaps this log contains some clues what went wrong.

If that doesn't help, try to enable debug logging / run you run config in debug mode.

In case you need more help locating the log files, please consult: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files

Comment: Hello Pim. I checked all idea logs . But there is no clue at tidea log. Intellij log is same as well. I will try enable debug logging

Comment: still no response from anywhere :( Anyone has any clue? Even Intellij support could not help me

Comment: Thats too bad. I have no clue... to help narrow down the issue could you try and install the latest version (trial or EAP for example) and see if you can reproduce the issue in the latest version? Just to rule out it's a bug in the older version...

Comment: Another suggestion: can you build your war and manually deploy it in a tomcat instance of the same version? To rule out there is something wrong with the artifact?