# How I get IntelliJ UE and Tomcat 9 to run my web application? (Mac OS)

Tags: macos, tomcat, intellij-idea, web, tomcat9

I have searched everywhere for this. I'm sure I have read the information correctly but can't seem to get a full understanding of it.

I used this tutorial to get things going (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/creating-and-running-your-first-web-application.html). I do everything step by step but when it comes to running my web app, The localhost shows the official page of Tomcat and not my index.jsp that I have created. I've tried every path combination to try to get my index to show but I have had no luck.

I have done a lot of googling on this and it seems to be that when I run tomcat it reads the files from the webapps/ROOT folder instead of my project folder. How can I get my intellij or tomcat to read the files from my project? I keep reading that its my run configurations but everything looks good to me, and no one really shows what to actually do.

I wouldn't be asking unless I have tried doing this my self for hours. I'm sorry if it is really simple I just can't see it and would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance

[Structure (Ignore error messages)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEKtu.jpg)

[Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBsct.png)

[Artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMDUl.png)

[Deployment tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaHbo.png)

[I always get routed to this web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHGUz.jpg)

[Artifact deployed successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oo53.png)

Comment: maybe post pics of your current run configurations/project structure?

Comment: @janDro I have edited the post.

Comment: @ChangYeaMoon your screenshots do not show the artifacts configuration and the deployment tab with the context specified.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Okay, I added those now

Comment: @ChangYeaMoon please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Do you use the vanilla Tomcat installation or did you modify any of Tomcat configs/startup scripts?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Sorry just added now, and how do I share that? I just followed the link I provided. It is as minimal as it can get with code, and by following the tutorial i believe I have eliminated any issues that aren't relevant to the problem. I just want a way for tomcat to read the index.jsp file in my project file and not the index.jsp in it's ROOT folder.

Comment: @ChangYeaMoon deployment fails for some reason, check the server logs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45666862/104891.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Sorry what is vanilla Tomcat? I used brew to install tomcat

Comment: @ChangYeaMoon "vanilla" means unmodified. MCVE means a zipped project directory that one can download, open on his machine and try to reproduce the problem you have. Try to download Tomcat .tar.gz, unpack it, configure in IntelliJ IDEA the unpacked location and use it instead of the Tomcat you've installed via brew. If the issue persists, share the server logs as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45666862/104891).

Comment: @CrazyCoder Sorry for the confusion the artifact error was from a past attempt at something else. I don't get any errors. I have also already using the unpacked location and get the same results. Do you want the server logs from CATALINA_BASE/logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you already have Tomcat service started on port 8080, therefore IntelliJ IDEA cannot start another instance and perform the deployment.

You need to shut down the service running on port 8080 so that IDE can start its own copy of the server and perform the configuration/deployment on start.

`brew services stop tomcat` should help in your case.

Comment: WOW. I knew it was something so simple and dumb. Thank you very much for your previous comments and now the solution!