# IntelliJ hot-swapping local tomcat Ant based deployment

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ant, hotswap

All of the hot swapping information I've read involved deploying an exploded war, which makes the run/debug configuration allow 'Update classes and resources'. However, I'm working with a legacy program that compiles and jdo-enhances with Ant, deploying a web folder that contains all of the jsp, css, libs, etc.

Is there a way I can make it work with my current setup? If not, please suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: Something like JRebel may work in your case, but IntelliJ IDEA will not work like that out of the box. Use the exploded web artifact as described in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html.

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder, I tried JRebel before and just now again: The startup URL always 404s on start. Do you know why that may be?

Comment: Check Tomcat logs for the URL where the app context is available and if the deployment went without errors.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Where might this log be located on a mac? I'm not seeing a log in the tomcat installation directory. my deployment application context under my deployment tab in the run/debug config is `/app` and my server URL points to localhost at `/app/start.do`. When I go to `/app` on the browser it hits one of my bg servers.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45666862/104891 if Tomcat is started from IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: I found that the `jrebel.xml` was just pointing to the wrong directory for the web link so the redirect on my index page wasn't getting hit. I adjusted it and it's working now.