# where is the server log for tomcat when running inside (Tomcat plugin) of Intellij?

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, tomee-8

Using  Intellij ultimate 2021.3.2 with tomcat & tomEE built in plugin to a run a grails app
And I need to access tomcat logs (server.log)
Any idea where I can find this on the Mac ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45666862/8203759

Comment: thanks, saw that earlier too and for some reason I can't locate no log files in those specified path/directories , and I don't also see catalina-home /base printed to the logs on start up of the grails app in IntelliJ

Comment: Search for `catalina.out` on your home directory or, get intellij PID and then `lsof -p <PID>` and take a look at the output