# Where does intellj deploy my /webapp code to?

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

So according to these sources:

[Where is my app placed when deploying to Tomcat using IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461702/where-is-my-app-placed-when-deploying-to-tomcat-using-intellij-idea)

and

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000667490-Where-does-intelliJ-save-projects-

Intellji should be:

```
${dir.to.idea.project}\YourWebApp\out\artifacts
```

which in my instance would

```
~/IdeaProjects/projectname/YourWebApp/out/artifacts
```

However there is only and empty dir under:

```
~/IdeaProjects/projectname/
```

I figure this may be the wrong project name folder is there any way to check this and confirm within the IDE.

Comment: What is the artifact output location? See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html. Do you have any web artifacts configured for this project?

Comment: /Users/mcerlane_w/git/ghix-web/target/ghix-web/ I'm guessing it just pulls from there? target has my ghix-web.war and ghix-web dir but no out folder only index.jsp META-INF resources and WEB-INF

Comment: So does it appear there after you Build | Build Artifacts?

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).