# IntelliJ web application context path

Tags: tomcat, deployment, intellij-idea

In my IntelliJ web app, I have set the application context to *myapp* as shown below

[image]

When I set the Application context, it doesn't seem to have any effect. I was expecting the app to be deployed to myapp, or at least the generated context.xml file to set my app's context to myapp. Any thoughts on why this doesn't work (does it have something to do with the fact that this is an exploded war)?

Comment: Can't reproduce, works just fine with a brand new project created with a wizard and vanilla Tomcat 7 installation, when context is specified in Deployment the app is available at `http://localhost:8080/myapp/` after running it from IDEA. Can you share a sample project that doesn't work properly? Please also specify your IDEA and Tomcat versions.

Comment: Let me try to reproduce a sample one, sure.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, did you set the output directory of the exploded war to be <tomcat-install>/webapps?

Comment: No, IDEA deployment [works differently](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7702077/104891).

Comment: Ah, maybe my problem has to do with how I have CATALINA_BASE set. I'll give it a try and post back what happens.

Comment: @CrazyCoder that was the problem. I'm going to close this question.

Comment: No need to close, you can accept the provided answer which may help other users having the same problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Overriding `CATALINA_BASE` in Tomcat startup script may break IDEA deployment as it works by supplying custom `CATALINA_BASE` location where the modified configuration is placed so that Tomcat loads artifacts directly from the location specified as the artifact output directory.

See the related question:

- [How is Tomcat handled by IntelliJ IDEA 10.5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7699354/104891)

Comment: This should be printed in GIANT BLINKING LETTERS in IDEA's 'edit configuration' dialog box. Total misery can lead from what seems like a rational decision to pass along `CATALINA_BASE` as environment variable.