# intellij in debug change where IDE loads the catalina.base

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using version 11.1.5 and using a tomcat server. 
I need to change where the tomcat runtime files are located with debugging 
for example in the console i see( see below) and i need to change where the catalina.base is created 
can not seem to find where that is set 
thanks

"D:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_41\bin\java" -Dcatalina.base=\MSC-USERS\USERS1\rp.IntelliJIdea11\system\tomcat\Unnamed_nlpValidateWS "-Dcatalina.home=D:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0" "-Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\temp" -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:3611,suspend=y,server=n -jar "D:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\bin\bootstrap.jar" start

Comment: Did you already check [these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7702077/104891) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13830456/104891)?

Comment: yeah this does not help. I need to tell intellij where to create the temp instance of tomcat when the debugger starts.

Comment: Why do you need to change it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me
[here is where the answer is](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23348963)

Answer (score 0):

add -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Windows\temp to the "VM options" in the configuration