# Change default web application directory in IntelliJ 12

Tags: jsp, web-applications, intellij-idea, tomcat7

From the output, I get;

INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\manager

What I need it to deploy is "root", and not "manager". After researching the topic and looking through IntelliJ's tutorials, I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this. This is my first attempt at a web app, so I apologize if I am overlooking something trivial.

I am also using Tomcat 7 as my application server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This message has nothing to do with your artifact deployment, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7702077/104891).

Web application is deployed directly from the directory that is set as the [output directory of your artifact](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-artifacts.html).

You can change artifact output to be `TOMCAT\webapps\ROOT`, but normally it's not needed.

**UPDATE**:

Check your `Run` configuration `Deployment` tab, did you specify the artifact to deploy and its context? Is the context set to "/" (ROOT)? You may also need to disable deploying applications already configured in this Tomcat instance, here are the relevant settings:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder, I think the issue is maybe I am asking the wrong question. When I run it, it does pull up the default screen that says "If you are seeing this, you've successfully installed Tomcat. Congratulations!" but I am trying to run the index.jsp that I have written found in the root folder (Which I created an artifact for).