# Set spring app to deploy to root folder on URL tomcat server

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, jakarta-ee, configuration, tomcat8

I am using tomcat 8.0.0 for running my Spring MVC java, I expected that my localhost to be http://localhost:8080

but it convert automatically to:

http://localhost:8080/SalmonController_war_exploded/

I tried to change my tomcat configuration URL to http://localhost:8080/ but its running with ..._war_exploded/

Artifacts problem or ...

[image]

Comment: Apps get deployed on their app name there are ways how to deploy it to root folder. What software are you using to deploy  this? Is it your IDE, if so which one is it?

Comment: yes this is my intellij IDE, using tomcat 8.0.0 and SPRING MVC java EE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change default web application directory in IntelliJ 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862032/change-default-web-application-directory-in-intellij-12)