# intelliJ tomcat deploy intermittent issue

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm running a Spring project on local, and pops out the following error intermittently during my development.

```
/Users/username-mac/Documents/Tools/apache-tomcat-7.0.75-st/bin/catalina.sh run
[2017-03-20 11:19:29,818] Artifact PortalFrontServer:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
...
Mar 20, 2017 11:19:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 66 ms
Connected to server

[2017-03-20 11:19:30,866] Artifact PortalFrontServer:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
Mar 20, 2017 11:19:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Mar 20, 2017 11:19:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Mar 20, 2017 11:19:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/CITIC_CLOUDSMS_UI] startup failed due to previous errors
[2017-03-20 11:19:33,163] Artifact PortalFrontServer:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
Mar 20, 2017 11:19:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Users/username-mac/Documents/Tools/apache-tomcat-7.0.75-st/webapps/manager
Mar 20, 2017 11:19:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /Users/username-mac/Documents/Tools/apache-tomcat-7.0.75-st/webapps/manager has finished in 50 ms
```

- The code has no error.
- I did not change anything to my tomcat config
- It just happens sometimes. The server is started but cannot deploy the project.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file`. Find the logs under `CATALINA_BASE` location printed in the console on start and check them for errors.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have no idea why my `/Users/username-mac/Documents/Tools/apache-tomcat-7.0.75-st/` is empty.

Comment: `CATALINA_BASE` is replaced with a temp location under [IDE system directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519), see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14487462/104891).