# IntelliJ and Tomcat deployment configuration naming/location?

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat8, intellij-14, intellij-13, intellij-15

I use IntelliJ 2016.3.4 and one Tomcat8 installation, I point my CATALINA_HOME to this one installation, my CATALINA_BASE I set to three different locations as I run and deploy three different web applications as:

```
-Dcatalina.base="C:\server\1"
-Dcatalina.home="C:\tools\apache-tomcat-8.0.41"
-Djava.endorsed.dirs="C:\tools\apache-tomcat-8.0.41\endorsed"
-Djava.io.tmpdir="C:\tools\apache-tomcat-8.0.41\temp"

-Dcatalina.base="C:\server\2"

-Dcatalina.base="C:\server\3"
```

Question 1. The three CATALINA_BASE directories above are emtpy, why?

IntelliJ puts everything under:

```
C:\Users\john\.IntelliJIdea2016.3\system\tomcat
```

In three directores:

```
Unnamed_mycompany
Sys_(1)_mycompany_2
Sys_(1)_mycompany
```

Question 2. I did not create the naming, how can i myself define the name of the directories?

Question 3. Where does the Unamed_ part come from?

Question 4. Should not everything land under CATALINA_BASE?

Comment: `CATALINA_BASE` is set via Tomcat Run configuration environment. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14487462/104891).

Comment: I already set CATALINA_BASE, see my questions 1-4