# Deploying Multiple projects on tomcat through IDEA

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I recently started using intellij IDEA as webapp development ide. I had a project with 4 components. war files of each component is generated and deployed using ide tomcat plugin to local tomcat server, it works fine. Now there is another folder say 'Images' in webapps folder of tomcat. This folder I am using it for hosting images of my app (I know its very bad idea, but thats not the point of discussion currently).

**As I am running and deploying app through IDEA, only the components those are deployed through IDEA are accessible. I can't access images (though they exists, I checked).**

Any solution for this?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14487462/104891).

Comment: You are right CrazyCoder, just answer this question I will give me tick to your answer, Thanks!