# Tomcat configuration in IntelliJ's Run Configuration

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat7

When I create a Run Configuration for local Tomcat, IntelliJ creates following folders:

```
$ ls ~/.IntelliJIdea2018.1/system/tomcat/Unnamed_my-app
conf  logs  work
```

with application logs (the original logs folder **/opt/tomcat/logs** stays empty) and conf folder.

So does it mean that if I want to change *server.xml*/*context.xml* or some other config file from conf folder I should change it in IntelliJ folder? 
And what if I create multiple configs pointing to the same Tomcat, which conf folder it will use?

From my experience it seems that when config is created it copies original conf folder, but I would like to have a reference to documentation about this feature.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14487462/8958060