# Cannot deploy project to tomcat inside intellij IDEA 14

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

When deploying project to tomcat server (I tried 7 and 8), error occurs:

**Artifact ch10-helloworld:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available**

Intellij IDEA version 14.
OS X 10.10

I cannot solve this problem for about week,  I've googled a lot, but nothin helped me. I've seen solutions in SO, they didn't helped me too.

Port 8080 is not used when I'm deploying application.

When I imported this project into Eclipse(Spring STS), deployment went without any problem.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Complete error log:

```
/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8/bin/catalina.sh run
[2015-09-22 08:37:39,147] Artifact ch10-helloworld:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.669 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.26
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.671 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Aug 18 2015 11:38:37 UTC
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.671 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.26.0
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.671 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Mac OS X
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.672 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.10.5
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.672 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          x86_64
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.673 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.673 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_20-b26
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.673 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.673 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/moreo/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea14/tomcat/Unnamed_ch10-helloworld_2
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.673 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.673 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/moreo/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea14/tomcat/Unnamed_ch10-helloworld_2/conf/logging.properties
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.674 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.674 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.674 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1098
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.675 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.676 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.676 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.677 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8/endorsed
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.677 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/moreo/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea14/tomcat/Unnamed_ch10-helloworld_2
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.678 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.678 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8/temp
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.678 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/moreo/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.793 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.810 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.813 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.815 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.815 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 429 ms
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.832 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.832 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.26
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.838 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.843 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
22-Sep-2015 20:37:39.844 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 29 ms
Connected to server
[2015-09-22 08:37:40,190] Artifact ch10-helloworld:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
22-Sep-2015 20:37:40.860 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'hello': initialization started
INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'hello-servlet': startup date [Tue Sep 22 20:37:41 GET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/myapp-config.xml]
INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/sayhello] onto handler of type [class sample.spring.chapter10.web.HelloWorldController]
INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'hello': initialization completed in 308 ms
[2015-09-22 08:37:41,348] Artifact ch10-helloworld:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2015-09-22 08:37:41,348] Artifact ch10-helloworld:war exploded: Deploy took 1,158 milliseconds
22-Sep-2015 20:37:49.839 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8/webapps/manager
22-Sep-2015 20:37:49.862 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8/webapps/manager has finished in 23 ms
```

Comment: Did you find any solid solution for this. I suck at the same thing. Plese share me the link or any specific answer.

Comment: I had the same issue. In Spring STS all worked fine but not in Intellij IDEA. What helped me is on last screenshot Run/Debug Configurations->Deployment->Application Context changed from just /. I used /my-artifact-name and all worked.