# How to set docBase on IntelliJ with Tomcat based OSX(MAC)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, tomcat, intellij-idea

I just wanna import external image files from another folder(not same root folder). but cannot find the solution setting similar "docBase for Eclipse". (I'v a file 'server.xml' for eclipse).

server.xml for eclipse

```
...
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
<Context docBase="~/Sites/LFM/uploadFiles/" path="/uploadFiles" reloadable="true"/>
...
```

How can I set docBase on IntelliJ based on OSX.

---

#### Run Configuration > Tomcat Server

- Server Tab

  - Application Server: Tomcat 7.0.55
  - Enabled 'Deploy applications configured in Tomcat instance'
- Deployment Tab

  - added '[project name]:war exploded', application context: '/'
- Startup/Connection Tab

  - Pass environment variables: No variables
- Before launch

  - Build -> Build '[project name]:war exploded' artifact

#### Project Structure

- Modules Tab > Sources

```
 - /Users/[computer name]/Sites/[project name]/web
  - src
    - main
    - test
  - target
    - apache-tomcat-maven-plugin
    - classes
    - generated-sources
    - [project name]-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
    - maven-archiver
    - tomcat
```

- Deployment Descriptors
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgpkc.png)
- Artifacts Tab
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHHJL.png)

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA generates `context.xml` with `docBase` that is set to the artifact output location.

Comment: @CrazyCoder sorry, could I show that example source bout above? I can't understand your explanation.

Comment: See these answers: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7702077/104891), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14487462/104891).

Comment: @CrazyCoder have no a easier or simply solution?